# Can't connect to azure vm's through network discovery

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, azure

Can't connect to azure vm's through network discovery.

I have enabled:

Function Discovery Resource publication
SSDP Discovery
Upnp Device host
and
DNS client

I have turned off all of the firewalls, just to test this out, I have also enabled network discovery on the machines involved, all I can seem to find is the machine that I am using and tsclient, all machines are on a .local domain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

With all that mentioned services activated network discovery is configured correctly. That is the reason you see your own machine.

Network discovery in Windows depends on [SSDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Service_Discovery_Protocol) which uses UDP multicast. Currently [virtual networks does not support multicast or broadcast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn133803.aspx#BKMK_VNETFAQVNETConfig).

Conclusion: Network discovery does not work currently in Azure even if it is configured correctly. That is the reason you are not seeing the other machines except the own one.